# Help me identify Grasshopper

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

I found this Grasshopper in **Goa/India.** It was about **2cm** long. I suspect it is from Cataloipus genus or Gomphocerinae subfamily. Am i correct or it also seems to be juvenile from some other species?

[image]

Comment: This does appear to be a juvenile; zooming in shows me wing buds.  Under those circumstances further identification is unlikely.